# Swap Node.js for IO.js in OpsWorks Node.js deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I'm using my own custom recipes for Node.js apps based on the default OpsWorks recipes: https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_nodejs I'm experimenting with our stack on IO.js today and was curious as to how these recipes install Node and where I can swap that package installation out for IO.

I can't seem to determine where this is occurring. default.rb seems to do that but it looks like it's done through the OpsWorks::PackageManagerHelper tool. I've attempted digging up documentation on that but can't find anything helpul.

Any insight would be super helpful.